# Derivation for identities involving Stirling Numbers and Binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Looking for a combinatorial derivation of the identities:

$${n\brack l+m} {l+m\choose l}
= \sum_k {k\brack l} {n-k\brack m} {n\choose k}$$

&

$${n\brace l+m} {l+m\choose l}
= \sum_k {k\brace l} {n-k\brace m} {n\choose k}$$

Also if the original publication can be cited for the above-mentioned results, I found these on wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number), which gives the reference to Concrete Mathematics (Graham, Knuth, Patashnik) but the book does not give further reference to the results.

Answer (score 2):

These are Identities 205 and 204 in *Proofs That Really Count: The Art of Combinatorial Proof*.  Their proofs are left as exercises, but hints are given in the back of the book.